# How to get the least used item?

Tags: python, python-2.6

Say you have a defaultdict of usage counts like this:

```
usage_counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
usage_counts['foo1'] = 3
usage_counts['foo2'] = 3
usage_counts['foo3'] = 1
usage_counts['foo4'] = 1
usage_counts['foo5'] = 56
usage_counts['foo6'] = 65
```

And you have candidates `foo1`, `foo3`, `foo4` and `foo5` in some list:

```
candidates = ['foo1', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5']
```

How can one pick randomly from the pool of least used candidates?

I came up with this function, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

```
def get_least_used(candidates, usage_counts):
    candidate_counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for candidate in candidates:
        candidate_counts[candidate] = usage_counts[candidate]
    lowest = min(v for v in candidate_counts.values())
    return random.choice([c for c in candidates if candidate_counts[c] == lowest])
```

Comment: What do you mean pick randomly for the least used candidates? If you are trying to find the least used candidate, why would you look randomly?

Comment: Yeah now that I think of it the random selection isn't that important because it will auto-level, but still.

Comment: If you change your datatype to `collections.Counter` you can get the lowest count item by doing `item, count == usage_counts.most_common()[-1]`

Comment: Darn it is in >= 2.7 and I am stuck with 2.6

Comment: No need for the generator expression.  `lowest = min(candidate_counts.itervalues())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
random.shuffle(candidates)

min_candidate = min(candidates, key=usage_counts.get)
```

returns the first "minimal" candidate from the shuffled list of candidates.

Answer (score 0):

You could browse the list only once if you accept to do it explicitely, by generating a list for the canditates having lowest count. If current count if less than old min, you initialize a new list, if equal you add to the list :

```
def get_least_used(candidates, usage_counts):
    mincount = sys.maxint
    for c in candidates :
        count = usage_counts[c]
        if count < mincount:
            leastc = [ c ]
            mincount = count
        elif count == mincount:
            leastc.append(c)
    return random.choice(leastc)
```

As you said you were using Python 2.6, I initialize `mincount` with `sys.maxint`. Under Python 3.x, you would have to choose a value *reasonably* great.